# exception when trying to select specific tab control

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabcontrol

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection appears when trying to select specific tab it it is solved when moving to that specific tab manually with the mouse any idea ?

Ohh it is to complicated here is the code which the code fails `tabDeviceConfig.SelectedTab = tabDeviceConfig.TabPages[4];`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFHw0.png)

Comment: There are lot of ideas, but better show your code.

Comment: I'm guessing the index you tried to use was "out of range"?...here's another comment telling you to post your code.

Comment: **WHERE** and **WHEN** is that line of code being used?  Are you by chance creating another instance of the Form that houses the TabControl?  Are any of the tabs created and/or removed dynamically?  Your comment of "Ohh it is to complicated" is not promising...

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 tabs.
tabDeviceConfig.TabPages[4] refers to the 5th tab.

Or more likely - your failing code is called before the tabs are setup.

Comment: please look at the attached picture you can see 5 tabs with indexes from 0 to 4

Comment: Then I guess the failing code is called before the tabs are set up.